# Cheapest multi-disk NAS?

Tags: nas, sbc, cheap

So, now there is a $25 [hat with 4 @ 6 GBit/s SATA](https://www.notebookcheck.net/FriendlyElec-NanoPi-M4-The-Raspberry-Pi-alternative-can-now-be-used-as-a-NAS-for-just-US-25-thanks-to-a-new-HAT-expansion-board.410432.0.html) for the $50 [FriendlyElec NanoPi M4](https://www.friendlyarm.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=234)

Hmm, that link speaks only of a 2gB version, whereas [this](https://www.androidpimp.com/boards/nanopi-m4-raspberry-pi-board-alternative/)  indicates that there is also a 4gB version.

[image]

Total $75 to replace the desktop that I currently use as a server? What’s not to like?

Given the SBCs available nowadays, does anyone know of batter bang/buck/simplicity way to create a NAS server at home?

It must have sufficient RAM to handle multiple disks being accessed simultaneously (I would prefer 4 disks, but could live with 2, I guess).

I dn't mind it being dedicated as a NAS server, and wouldn't use it for anything else.

Simplicity of setup plays a role (certainly no soldering involved), as does durability, cooling, etc.

In my case, I would like to attach it to my router by Ethernet, but can forego that. It must, however, be WiFi accessible.

Comment: NASs are one of those things where features and compute power really can matter. As cool as this is—and useful as it can be—you are going to be severely compute and RAM limited compared to a more powerful computer running something like FreeNAS. While this isn't an outright bad solution, it is a limited one. It's easy and cheap, but probably not the most performant. As with many hardware-recommendation related requests, choose two of three: simplicity, value, performance.

Comment: Based on the fact that you already have a desktop that you're currently using, it seems to me that your main concern is power draw and space usage, but it's hard to tell exactly what you want with this question is written. So, I think this ends up being a bit of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I would recommend editing this question so we can give you better directed solutions to your needs. What exactly are you using this NAS for? How fast (specifically) does it need to be? How is it connected to its clients? What's your budget? Power limits? Space concerns? Noise concerns? Do you need more disks, or are you willing to use what hardware you've got? What hardware do you have? Would you be okay reusing components from your existing desktop? Would you be willing to buy used?